# How do I get a call recording url in twilio when programming in PHP?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am completely new to Twilio and I need the call recording url of multiple phone calls, made from one account but with different sub-accounts and with an authority token. How to go about it?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Each recording has an ID, something like `RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.

The url for MP3 format is

`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp3?Download=false`

You can also get the url for WAV fromat

`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.wav?Download=false`

Also, observe the Download=false query string parameter.

Comment: Twilio docs don't really mention (that I could find anyway) what the base URL was/is for this. THANK YOU for posting the full URL here!