# Twilio download recording to file throwing error on JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()

Tags: c#, download, twilio, content-type, webrequest

I'm trying to download my recordings on Twilio to a file on my servers local file system (so I can send them to another storage location), but following the code that I've found is throwing an error on the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() call.

The code that I found is here (called "Retrieve the actual recording media"): https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource#filter-by-participant-sid

Here's the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    const string apiKeySid = "SKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    const string apiKeySecret = "your_api_key_secret";

    const string recordingSid = "RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    const string uri = $"https://video.twilio.com/v1/Recordings/{recordingSid}/Media";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiKeySid + ":" + apiKeySecret)));
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    string responseBody = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    var mediaLocation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseBody)["redirect_to"];

    Console.WriteLine(mediaLocation);
    new WebClient().DownloadFile(mediaLocation, $"{recordingSid}.out");
}
```

And here's my version:

```
        var twilioRecordingUri = $"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{recording.AccountSid}/Recordings/{recording.Sid}.mp3?Download=true";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(twilioRecordingUri));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{apiKeySid}:{apiKeySecret}")));
        request.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
        //request.Accept = "audio/mpeg";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        var responseBody = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseBody);
        var mediaLocation = deserialized["redirect_to"];

        new WebClient().DownloadFile(mediaLocation, $"{recording.Sid}.out");
```

But executing that code, it fails on the JsonConvert.Deserialize(), like I mentioned; it throws this generic Json error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

Hovering over my "responseBody" variable does show that it's a really long string of funky characters.

My thought was that I should be adding either the "Accept" or "Content-type" to "audio/mpeg" since that's the type of file that I'm trying to retrieve. But when checking Dev Tools at both the request and response headers, neither the Accept or Content-type ever get my audio/mpeg setting that I just specified.

What's wrong with this code here?

**Edit:** for anyone that noticed the download URL is different from Twilio's example, I found this page that had the updated URL: [How do I get a call recording url in twilio when programming in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582466/how-do-i-get-a-call-recording-url-in-twilio-when-programming-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the call you're trying to make is to download an `.mp3` file and not a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so it's likely hitting an error when attempting to deserialize a string into a type that it doesn't match. What you're probably seeing as a result is a `Base64` string, especially based on your description. Without seeing at least a sample of the data, I can't know for sure, but I'd guess that you're downloading the raw `.mp3` file instead of the file information with location (redirect_to).

If the result is a pure `Base64` string, you should be able to convert it to an array of bytes and write that directly to a file with whatever filename you want. That should get you the `mp3` file that you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only posting this answer to show what the "working" version looks like. It was @Grungondola 's answer that prompted me. Thanks goes to him (as well as the accepted answer).

```
private async Task DownloadRecording(RecordingResource recording, string fileName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName is required when downloading a recording.");

    var twilioRecordingUri = $"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{recording.AccountSid}/Recordings/{recording.Sid}.mp3?Download=false";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(twilioRecordingUri));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{apiKeySid}:{apiKeySecret}")));
    request.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

    var virtualPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(fileName);
    var fileStream = new FileStream(virtualPath, FileMode.Create);

    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out. Trying to figure out the format of responses is always the most difficult piece of making WebRequest calls.